# Heat equation proof

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

> Let $S(x,t)=\dfrac1{\sqrt{4\pi kt}}\exp\left(\dfrac{-x^2}{4kt}\right)$ be the heat kernel of the seat equation $u_t=k_{xx}$ on $\mathcal{R}$. Show that for any $\delta>0$, $\lim\limits_{t\to0}\max\limits_{|x|>\delta}S(x,t)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{t\to0}\int_{|x|>\delta}S(x,t)\,\mathrm dx=0$.

Maximum principle: If u(x,t) satisfies the heat equation in the rectangle $R={0 \leq x \leq l, 0 \leq t \leq T}$ in space-time, then the maximum value of u(x,t) over the rectangle is assumed either initially (t=0), or on the lateral sides( x=0, or x =l)

I remember as a fact that maximum principle holds true for heat equation, can I argue using max principle only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is at least a solution using more basic ideas.

For both parts, just make use of the basic inequality $e^x\leq -\frac{1}{x}$ for $x<0$ to get that

$$S(x,t)\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 k \pi t}}\frac{4kt}{x^2}=\frac{\sqrt{4 kt}}{\sqrt{\pi} x^2}$$

Now both parts are immediate.

As for maximum principle as you stated it, I don't think that helps here because your heat equation is on all of $\mathbb R$.